# What is the word for nouns that used to be specific, but are now ambiguous?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I once discovered a word with a fascinating description but have forgotten it.

The word refers to nouns that at one time meant something very specific, but would now be ambiguous and needs an accompanying word to specify further. The best example is 'guitar'. Once, the word unequivocally referred to an acoustic guitar, but would now need 'acoustic' added, lest it be confused with electric guitar, bass guitar, etc.

Comment: Good catch, @ermanen! Maybe today's just a bad day, but I was beginning to feel like I'm the only user who bothers to identify duplicates!

Comment: I don’t think the linked questions answers OP’s question here.  The answer given there (*retronym*) is the term given to the ***new*** term, i. e., *electric guitar*  OP’s question is asking about the word *guitar*  which used to be unambiguous but now requires the retronym.